# What would be the best way to write this query in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using this query to get count of clicks, conversions, payout and revenue from an offer.
Now the issue is the query is taking around 1 minute to run for 26 offers and around 15k click overall.

Here is my query

```
$offers=Offers::select('offer_id','offer_name','offer_currency')
        ->with(['currency' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('currency_id', 'currency_symbol');
}])
        ->when($request->filter_offer, function($query) use ($request){
            return $query->where('offer_id', $request->filter_offer);
        })
       ->whereHas('clicks', function($q) use ($date_from,$date_to){
                               $q->whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to]);
               })
        ->withCount(['conversions'=> function($q) use ($date_from,$date_to){
                    $q->whereBetween('conversion_date_time', [$date_from, $date_to]);
    }])
    ->withCount(['clicks'=> function($q) use ($date_from,$date_to){
        $q->whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to]);
    }])
    ->withCount(['conversions AS payout' => function ($query) use ($date_from,$date_to) {
                $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(conversion_payout) as payout"))
                    ->whereBetween('conversion_date_time', [$date_from, $date_to]);
            }])
        ->withCount(['conversions AS revenue' => function ($query) use ($date_from,$date_to) {
            $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(conversion_revenue) as revenue"))
                ->whereBetween('conversion_date_time', [$date_from, $date_to]);
        }])
    ;

    return Datatables::of($offers)->make(true);
```

Now this report is dynamic, User can generate the report on the basis of dates and the offer. This application will have more than 100 offers and more than 100million clicks. That time this gonna take a lot of time to generate this report.

What would be the best way to write this query?

Comment: I'd suggest start with commenting and find where it's slowing down. I bet it's `whereHas`

Comment: Also, Eloquent is powerful - but I would rather considering writing this as a custom raw query, much more room for optimization.